# Access XMLHttpRequest from Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, internet-explorer-11

I am developing a web application in **Ember 2.3.0** and while doing some cross-browser testing, it became apparent the slowness of the application for **IE 11**.
Doing some measurements on the IE developer's console seems that the *DOM onreadystatechange* event eats up to 100% CPU for a period of time, which could be a leak.

I found this article: http://milan.adamovsky.com/2012/02/javascript-memory-leaks-in-internet.html that despite being old it encouraged me to test the approach of nulling the *onreadystatechange* event in case it is a memory leak.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
    // code on completion

    ajax.onreadystatechange = CollectGarbage;
    ajax = null;
  }
};
```

But in Ember I don't know how to access the XMLHttpRequest object directly. The JSONApiAdapter provides with an ajax method to rewrite but I don't see how I can access the raw object:

```
const Adapter = DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  ajax: function(){ ... }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually deliberately not easy to get to the raw XHR object (see https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/4406). At some point Ember Data may switch to using fetch instead of XHR and they'd like the ability to make the switch easily.

If you suspect a leak you might try some of the suggestions at https://github.com/ember-best-practices/memory-leak-examples They're pretty useful